# If one wanted to study the Riemann Hypothesis, what should they study?

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

I've seen posts of a similar nature that list numerous books and papers about the Riemann Hypothesis. But, assuming one has no knowledge of the subject, where should they start studying?

Comment: Calculus, Analysis and Complex Variables. However, if your goal is to prove it, don't waste your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the statement of Riemann hypothesis and which clues determined its formulation, you need to know the basic notions about complex analysis (up to Residue theorem, I would say) plus some knowledge of (normal) convergence of series and infinite products. Also the basic facts about the Gamma (and Beta) function should be known (especially Wielandt uniqueness theorem and duplication formula). Then you can go through Euler product formula, as well as Riemann integral representation and relation for the zeta function. That should suffice to give a proper context to Riemann hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

My crazy High School teacher left me the task of writing an article that could explain it to a high school student. I must warn you the work is not of the highest quality. The main problem was I didn't understand it either (I still don't).

Regardless, here is the article. I hope it helps more than it harms.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2JIjrFh1hH6VVY2MlgyZU9oalU/edit?usp=sharing